# What is the use of automated UI Testing?

Tags: android, user-interface, testing, android-espresso

I was reading about writing tests for android apps and I cannot quite understand why should I use UI testing instead of testing the app by myself in real time? Can you give me some examples when UI testing is useful?

Comment: Automated tests pay for themselves the *second* time you run them (and the third, fourth, fifth and so on).  If you're only ever going to test your app *once,* then you don't need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automated testing in general is good for one key reason: it is automated.

Manual testing is unavoidable. However, it is slow, and as a result developers often do not test as frequently or as thoroughly as they should.

Writing automated tests — whether for UI elements or anything else — makes it easier to run the tests and get confirmation that everything still works. Automated tests help with the "thoroughly" problem, in that the automated tests do not get tired, bored, hungry, sleepy, grumpy, etc. Automated tests that themselves are run automatically — such as on every commit to a version control system, via a continuous integration (CI) server — help with the "frequently" problem.

How important automated tests are depends on the size of the project and the size of the user base. For an app that you are just using for yourself, or simply as a "proof of concept" with no actual users, manual testing is just fine. I do not have automated tests for the hundreds of sample apps in my book, for example. On the other hand, large projects might have more test code than production code, with very sophisticated test processes (e.g., automated testing against a fleet of devices, to help uncover regressions that only affect certain OS versions).

In the end, your question has little to do with Android, and more with software development in general, and I suspect that is why it is attracting downvotes.